# How to automatically sync a Hive external table with a MySQL table without using Sqoop?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hdfs

I'm already having a MySQL table in my local machine (Linux) itself, and I have a Hive external table with the same schema as the MySQL table.

I want to sync my hive external table whenever a new record is inserted or updated. Batch update is ok with me to say hourly.
What is the best possible approach to achieve the same without using sqoop?

Thanks,
Sumit

Comment: Updates and deletes are _not_ welcome in Hive / HDFS. Anyway, whatever Sqoop can do, Spark can do too - with some custom code. It's the final MERGE that will be either inefficient or tricky -- see what Uber did with Hoodie. Or what Cloudera did with Kudu.

Answer (score 0):

Without scoop, you can create table STORED BY **JdbcStorageHandler**. Project repository: **https://github.com/qubole/Hive-JDBC-Storage-Handler** It will work as usual hive table, but query will run on MySQL. Predicate pushdown will work.

```
DROP TABLE HiveTable;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE HiveTable(
  id INT,
  id_double DOUBLE,
  names STRING,
  test INT
)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storagehandler.JdbcStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  "mapred.jdbc.driver.class"="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
  "mapred.jdbc.url"="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rstore",
  "mapred.jdbc.username"="root",
  "mapred.jdbc.input.table.name"="JDBCTable",
  "mapred.jdbc.output.table.name"="JDBCTable",
  "mapred.jdbc.password"="",
  "mapred.jdbc.hive.lazy.split"= "false"
);
```