# Read data from hive and display it on dashboard

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, hbase

I have scenario where I want to create dashboard. Dashboard has charts and I can filter charts by month, week and date range etc. I have integrated Hbase and hive. I want to read data from hive and display it on dashboard. Please suggest some pointers.

I know hive partitioning, however data is in Hbase format in hadoop. I am not sure about partitioning is good fit or pull desired data from hive and put it in mysql.

Comment: JDBC storage handler to write to MYSQL table using Hive: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51050552/2700344 or use sqoop export

Comment: Yes this is correct. Data is in hbase/hadoop. I want to run one job to create desired tables(in mysql or hbase itself) which will hold all count of data. That is I need to perform some analytics to get all counts of data. Which tool(like hive, spark, spark+hive) will be best choice to write such job. This my actual problem. please help.

Comment: For analytics IMHO better to use Hive+Tez. because it is easy to write and support, scalable unlimited.

Comment: If you have integrated Hive with Hbase, then you can use JDBC/ODBC to create dashboards in any tool that supports SQL on Hive

Comment: ok. got it. thanks both of you