# how to copy rows from mysql to hive without using sqoop

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

I have to copy a whole mysql table from there to hive.
I cannot use sqoop.

I found a way getting the whole dataset from mysql and, row by row (looping into the dataset), copying into hive...

but it is a very slow method (50k rows need hours in my cluster)

is it a way like "***insert into mysql select * from hive***"?

thank you
marco

Comment: you don't need to copy row by row. get the dataset, move it into table location in HDFS or wherever your Hive table points to, and do table "repair" to sync the update with metastore

Comment: do you mean something like this?

    `sql = "SELECT * FROM mysqldb.mysqltable"`
    `cur.execute(sql)`
    `result_set = cur.fetchall()`
    `hdfs dfs -put -f result_set /myhdfsroot/myhdfsfolder`

Comment: apologize for my unformatted comment, still not learnt how to format them...

Comment: yes. and if your Hive table uses specific field delimiters and line terminators, add them into dataset prior to moving it into HDFS. otherwise the dataset will not be visible inside Hive

Comment: Using JdbcStorageHandler you can connect from Hive directly to mysql: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51050552/2700344

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you use sqlplus to execute query and load data into file and and then put this file into HDFS

```
  sqlplus -s user/password@dbname <<EOF
set feedback off trimspool on 
spool file_name.txt;
select * from table_name;
spool off;
exit;
EOF
```

once you get your data into file file_name.txt
 you can directly put the data into hdfs

```
hadoop fs -put file_name.txt /myhdfsfolder/
```